# Better way to set global variable for IP address in AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a number of AsyncTasks in which all their `doInBackground` methods do this:

```
Socket s = new Socket("12.345.67.89", 5555);
```

I want to set one global variable they can all access so when I change locations/IPs I don't have to comb through all the class files and change each IP address.

Off the top of my head I thought to make a class called `GlobalInfo` which contains all the (static?) variables I might need to share and then in each `doInBackground` call:

```
GlobalInfo derp = new GlobalInfo();
GlobalInfo.getIp();
```

But is there a better way to do this than my instantiating a new class each time approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need something like this, I would suggest creating a utility class (asa you wrote), with, for example:

```
public static final HOST_ADDRESS = "12.345.67.89";
```

Then in all your tasks (or even all classes) you can use it Like so (no need for instantiation whatsoever) :

```
MyUtilityClass.HOST_ADDRESS
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Make a static class

```
public class GlobalInfo {
    public static final String IP_ADDRESS = "123.123.123.123";

}
```

and access it by

```
 Socket s = new Socket(GlobalInfo.IP_ADDRESS, 5555);
```

or

```
import static GlobalInfo.*;

Socket s = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, 5555);
```

since its static creation only happens once.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a constants class, and make the members of that class static, so that you don't need to create a new object everytime.

Something like:

```
public class C {
    public static final String IP = "12.345.67.89";
    public static final int PORT = 5555;
}
```

and then access it using:

```
Socket s = new Socket(C.IP, C.PORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use global static constants:

```
public class GlobalInfo {
    public static final String IP_ADDRESS = "12.345.67.89";
    public static final int PORT = 5555;

    private GlobalInfo(){}
}
```

then, your code becomes:

```
Socket s = new Socket(GlobalInfo.IP_ADDRESS, GlobalInfo.PORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

All other answers are correct, but personally I opt to create an XML file with the content

```
<string name="server_ip">192.168.1.100</string>
```

and then simply do

```
getString(R.string.server_ip)
```

This way you keep configuration settings separated from code.